# Two onClickListeners. Can't start program

Tags: java, android

I want to program two buttons. One should recognize my voice and the other one should use the text-to-speech function. When I speak, the text goes to text2 and the tts is meant take this text. When I write the code separately (VoiceRecognition in one Project, TTs in another), it works. But I wanted to join these two functions, but when I start the program it crashes right away.

```
private Button btnSpeak;
private Button btnHear;
private EditText txtText;
private TextToSpeech tts;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    // Button for VoiceRecognition
    btnHear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    // OnClickListener for btnHear
    btnHear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "de-DE");
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_OK);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                   //Toast.makeText(...);
                }
            }

    });

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    // Button for TTS
    btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2);

    // button on click event
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            speakOut();
        }

    });
}
```

**Log:**

```
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.logos_daswortgottes/com.example.logos_daswortgottes.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280):     at com.example.logos_daswortgottes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
10-03 20:54:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(9280):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What error do you get in the logcat?

Comment: why you declare tts twice?! please put logcat

Comment: In your xml you have it set as an ImageButton not a button, but why are you setting it twice?

Answer (score 1):

Your buttonSpeak and buttonHear are declared as buttons in your activity but from your logcat, it looks like you are using them to point to ImageButton objects (at least either one or possibly both).

Since it looks like you intend to use image buttons, change the reference of buttonHear and buttonSpeak in the activity to ImageButton (but that's just a suggestion).